# Undefine method DataTime:: after migrate to PHP 7

Tags: php, datetime

In project I don't use any special frameworks, just plain PHP. 2 weeks ago I migrated project to PHP 7. All settings in php.ini are the same as in 5.6.

So what I done:

- migrate from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.0.10
- update Apache to 2.4.23
- all libraries are x64 and MSVC14

Problem is, that after update in php error log I have several times a day an error like this:

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DateTime::diff() in C:(...)\currencyImport.php

It's not necessarily `diff()` method. Somtimes it's `format()` method. Errors are only in `DateTime` library or my own extention of this library. On php 5.6 were no such errors.

I found nothing in google.

```
$last = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y H:i:s', '12.06.2016 13:18:00', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw'));
if ($last == NULL) {
    return true;
}

$today = new DateTime();
$interval = $today->diff($last); //fire error
$isToday = $interval->days == 0;
```

Comment: Can you share the code responsible from currencyImport.php?

Comment: Are you using any namespacing?

Comment: No in this class. Moreover this error is throwed not always. Class is called very often (this code fragment) and finished without error. Only a few times a day. And not (as I wrote before) only in this class and not only this DateTime method. Very strange.

Comment: Since it's not thrown all the time, my guess is that there's a call made by a PHP with a version < 5.3. So all your PHP7 calls work but not PHP<5.3.
Check your server for other php installation. maybe a cli call?